# C file complied wrongly

Tags: c

I'm currently reading a book 'Introducing Speech and Language Processing'.

In the book lets me know a code that generates 200Hz cosine wave.

Below is the code. (file name is coswave.c)

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  int length, status, i;
  short int *x;
  float freq;
  double arg, twopi;
  FILE *file_id;

  length = 8000;
  freq = 0.025;
  twopi = 8.0 * atan(1.0);
  arg = twopi * freq;

  x = (short int *) calloc(length, sizeof(short int));

  if (!x) {
    printf("Unable to allocate space for samples\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    x[i] = (short int) 32000 * cos(i * arg);

  file_id = fopen("cosine.dat", "wb");
  
  if (file_id == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  status = fwrite(x, sizeof(short int), length, file_id);
  
  if (status < length) {
    printf("Unable to write all samples\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fclose(file_id);
  return 0;
}
```

After writing that code, in the cmd, I typed the below.

```
gcc -c coswave.c // this command gives me coswave.o file
gcc -o bleep.exe coswave.o // this command gives md bleep.exe file
```

After that, I executed bleep.exe file and cosine.dat is created.

I opened it with 'hexdump for VSC' extension, but except a first line all contents are filled with 00.

```
00000000: 00 7D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    .}..............
```

What is wrong here?

```c
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    x[i] = (short int) 32000 * cos(i * arg);
    printf("%d %d \n", i, x[i]);
}
```

According to `printf()`, There is no problem with cosine values.

My OS is Windows and I used mingw gcc. Thank you very much.

Comment: When you print the values, what are the first few outputs?

Comment: I ran your code and did not duplicate your results. I didn't plot the data, but the hexdump has a repeating pattern as one would expect for a cosine wave.

Comment: not getting a linking error for failing to link in the math library?

Comment: Hi, I tried on linux (no windows around) and it seems to work like a charm. At least I have a 16000 bytes long cosine.dat file full of data. (compiled with gcc a.c -lm and ran ./a.out)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 0 32000 / 1 31606 / 2 30433 / 3 28512 / 4 25888 ... these values.

Comment: @yano No, I didn't get any complie errors.

Comment: I get a hex dump of `007D 767B E176 606F 2065 6358 7949 BF38` 16-bit little-endian, compiled with MSVC. It repeats every 80 samples.

Comment: Nobody can duplicate your problem (not writing to file, but the [output here looks valid](https://godbolt.org/z/enzzad1Tf)). I suspect you're not running an executable representative of your code for some reason or another. Delete bleep.exe and coswave.o and try `gcc coswave.c -o bleep.exe`, is the executable generated?

Comment: @yano Yes I got .exe file. After executing the exe file I got the same 'blank' .dat file. Maybe It will be a good thing to reinstall gcc.

Comment: humor me one more time .. should've said delete the .dat file too... you're sure it's getting overwritten/modified each time you run? I'm still at a loss as to why you're not getting linking errors, maybe mingw on Windows works some behind-the-scenes magic to link in the math library for you? That's not the case in any linux dev environment I've worked in, including the godbolt link from my previous comment (remove `-lm` and you'll see the linking error(s)).

Comment: I don't repro either. I suspect Windows shenanigans involving UAC.

Comment: @yano I tried 64 bit mingw but in vain... Still same result. Of course I deleted all file except .c file. I think C hates me...ㅠㅅㅠ while I try to love C... So I think it is a right decision to let C go. I'm going to use Node.js to write file... JavaScript maybe likes me... Thank you for helping me a lot!!

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you all for helping me!!!

Answer (score 0):

!!!!!!!!!!!!! I just fixed the problem!!!!@!!@!@!@!@!@!@

I think THE ANSWER is >>>>> reboot <<<<<

in order to try, I installed Visual Studio and it seemed I needed to reboot.
At that point I just thought "oh come to think of it I did not try two basic solutions: 1) reboot computer 2) hit computer". After rebooting, I just complied the file and it was so successful!!! But I'm not sure whether rebooting is the key or installing visual studio is the key. Anyways I think rebooting did some job...

Now everything is clear... C doesn't hate me... it just turns out that something was alienating me from C... Now I'm crying with delight...

Comment: hah, glad you got it working!